# Is “Arriving late to the party, but dancing on all the clichés” an adaptation of a cliché?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Yesterday’s (June 12) New York Times introduced Guggenheim’s new ventures of collecting artworks from South and South east Asia, Middle East, North Africa, and Latin America, which it has paid little attention to in the past under the headline, [“Arriving Late to the Party, but Dancing on All the Clichés”](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/06/13/arts/design/under-the-same-sun-art-from-latin-america-at-guggenheim.html?src=dayp&_r=0) in its Art & Design section.

I am intrigued with the phrase “Arriving late to the party, but dancing on all the xxx.” 
Is it a popular idiom or cliché? What does "dance on all the clichés" mean?

I guess it is a twist of “Arriving late to the party, but dancing  all the night (snugly).” But I’m not sure.

Comment: It's hard to tell. I actually don't think there's a pattern here other than the metaphor of coming late to a party, and then following that metaphor to metaphorical conclusion. At a party one might dance, so it's an attempt at a clever way of saying that the museum is very late in trying to do world art, and now that they have, they're not being very innovative they're just repeating cliche's that other museums did a long time ago.

Comment: @Mitch: I should think *dancing on all the clichés* is more of an allusion to *dancing on **the graves of** those clichés* (i.e. - making good and sure they're dead and buried, and specifically ***not*** reviving/repeating them).

Comment: @Yoichi: It's more "creative use of language" than anything else. I don't think *dancing on all the xxx's* has any meaningful level of currency, which is presumably why me and Mitch end up with opposite interpretations. But the article itself is obviously *approving* of the Guggenheim’s new venture, so it seems unlikely it would imply there's anything clichéd going on. I'd say it's *arriving late, but getting **stuck in*** (enthusiastically getting on with things, with the implication of ***having fun***).

Comment: @Fumblefingers. I feel it a great honor and pleasure to have had attention, kind answer, and comments from the site moguls like you, Robusto-san, and English language pundits like Mitch, and Medica on this question. It's far more than votes.

Comment: @ Yoichi: Be assured the honour is mutual (and I don't mind that you side with the Americans rather than Brits when it comes to spelling! :). I still try to help my nonagenarian father learn to play guitar (partly because we both hope it might keep the arthritis at bay!) But he doesn't consistently put as much *effort* into it as you do into mastering English - it's really that which makes me feel proud to be one of those assisting you in your ongoing struggle with our "less-than-helpful" language!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's not an idiom (or a cliché) of the kind you describe. Rather, it's a mixture of an idiom (arriving late to the party) and a metaphor (stomping out clichés).

The writer claims the Guggenheim stopped taking a focused interest in Latin American art in the 1960s, which was a mistake. It's trying to redress this error by adding a (small but significant) collection of such works, but the author asks "where do you enter a conversation when you’re late to the party?" He goes on to state:

> Latin America itself has long been viewed, from the outside, *through clichés, and artists are clever at* **shooting them down**. Tropical wilderness? In a piece called “Walk,” by the Cuban artist Wilfredo Prieto, untamed nature is a single tropical plant to be trundled around in a wheelbarrow. Postcard-perfect Eden? (etc.)

Finally, he praises the small, but on target, Latin American exhibit:

> What shouldn’t change is the curatorial energy, however low key, that’s been set in motion. Yes, our big museums are embracing a wider world late, and for dubious reasons. But late is better than never. And in enlightened hands, wrong reasons can be made right.

Hence the title: *Arriving Late to the Party, but Dancing on All the Clichés*.

Comment: +1 for ***stomping out** clichés* as a rephrasing of *dancing on [all the] clichés*.